# Short and sweet LINQ to merge objects in a List with same 'ID' property and add up its 'quantity' property?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, list

I'm looking for a solution to a problem as per title. I'm particularly looking at LINQ. If there's another better way, please suggest as well.

Example:
I have a List of Items with ID and Quantity properties of the following:
[0] - ID (5), Quantity (10)
[1] - ID (9), Quantity (8)
[2] - ID (9), Quantity (2)
[3] - ID (2), Quantity (5)
[4] - ID (5), Quantity (5)

Desired result:
[0] - ID (2), Quantity (5)
[1] - ID (5), Quantity (15)
[2] - ID (9), Quantity (10)

Thanks for your attention.

ps. Vote me down as much as you want if it makes you feel more accomplished in life, like as if it will affect me in any possible way.
My question is valid and not a duplicate, and enough research is put into it to know that LINQ is effective, but my manipulation of it is not good enough to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb337919(v=vs.100).aspx) operation.

```
list.GroupBy(i => i.Id).Select(g => new { Id = g.Key, Total = g.Sum(i => i.Quantity) });
```

Comment: Thanks. Just to find out a bit further, is there a way to update the quantity directly to the list something along the line like this: list = list.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID).Select(g => g.First().IssueQty = g.Sum(i => i.IssueQty)).ToList();

Of course in this example, it returns List<int>, which is not what I want. I would like something like g.First() with the quantity already updated into g.First().

Comment: Semantically, it seems like you would want to create a special type for groupings to roll up the sum of the quantities into since it likely has a different real world meaning to the original items being summed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary where the key is the id and the value is the sum of the quantites for that id:

Assuming you have a simple class with Id and Qty properties:

```
public class Order { public int Id { get; set; } public int Qty { get; set; }}
```

You can merge them like this:

```
var orders = new List<Order>
{
    new Order {Id = 5, Qty = 10},
    new Order {Id = 9, Qty = 8},
    new Order {Id = 9, Qty = 2},
    new Order {Id = 2, Qty = 5},
    new Order {Id = 5, Qty = 5},
};
var combinedOrders = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach (var order in orders)
{
    if (combinedOrders.ContainsKey(order.Id))
        combinedOrders[order.Id] += order.Qty;
    else
        combinedOrders.Add(order.Id, order.Qty);
}

foreach (var combinedOrder in combinedOrders.OrderBy(o => o.Key))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", combinedOrder.Key, combinedOrder.Value);
}

// Output:
// 2: 5
// 5: 15
// 9: 10
```